# Convolution with a particular delta sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be locally integrable and define a function $\rho_L$ for $L>0$ by $$\rho_L(x) := \frac1{x\ln L} 1_{[1/L,1]}(x).$$
Obviously $\int\rho_L = 1$. Is it true that the convolution $f*\rho_L(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in the $L\to\infty$ limit almost everywhere? The fact that this $\rho_L$ is not a approximation to the identity (i.e., not a scaled version of some $\rho_1$) makes the standard proofs (using Hardy-Littlewood's maximal function) not applicable, it seems to me.

Comment: By "converges", do you mean "converges for $L\to1^+$"?

Comment: @joriki: I meant the $L\to\infty$ limit; I just edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: For continuous functions it is true.  Just split the integral up into two pieces at the point $L^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$.  The piece close to the singularity will give you $(1-\alpha)f(x)$ as $L\to \infty$ and the other piece is bounded above by $\alpha \|f\|_\infty$.  Then send $\alpha\to 0$. Not sure about locally integrable, but you can probably use a density argument or something.